# Why does my isomorphic Cycle.js app cause an xstream exception when rendering on server?

Tags: javascript, isomorphic-javascript, cyclejs, hapi.js, xstream-js

I am trying to write a demo isomorphic [Cycle.js](http://cycle.js.org/)/[Hapi.js](http://hapijs.com/) app, but it fails with an exception in xstream while rendering on the server. What is going wrong here? I've based my app on [Cycle.js' isomorphic app example](https://github.com/cyclejs/cyclejs/blob/master/examples/isomorphic).

The traceback looks like this:

```
TypeError: Uncaught error: s[i]._add is not a function
    at CombineProducer._start (/Users/arve/Projects/hapi-cycle/node_modules/xstream/core.js:190:22)
    at Stream._add (/Users/arve/Projects/hapi-cycle/node_modules/xstream/core.js:976:19)
    at MapOperator._start (/Users/arve/Projects/hapi-cycle/node_modules/xstream/core.js:717:18)
    at Stream._add (/Users/arve/Projects/hapi-cycle/node_modules/xstream/core.js:976:19)
    at LastOperator._start (/Users/arve/Projects/hapi-cycle/node_modules/xstream/core.js:596:18)
    at Stream._add (/Users/arve/Projects/hapi-cycle/node_modules/xstream/core.js:976:19)
    at Stream.addListener (/Users/arve/Projects/hapi-cycle/node_modules/xstream/core.js:1050:14)
    at Object.streamSubscribe (/Users/arve/Projects/hapi-cycle/node_modules/@cycle/xstream-adapter/lib/index.js:39:16)
    at /Users/arve/Projects/hapi-cycle/node_modules/@cycle/base/lib/index.js:49:30
    at Array.map (native)
```

The render code looks basically as follows:

```
import Cycle from '@cycle/xstream-run'
import xs from 'xstream'
import {html, section, h1, p, head, title, body, div, script, makeHTMLDriver,} from '@cycle/dom'
import serialize from 'serialize-javascript'
import Logger from '@arve.knudsen/js-logger'
let logger = Logger.get('server.rendering')

let wrapVTreeWithHtmlBoilerplate = ([vtree, context,]) => {
  return (
    html([
      head([
        title('Cycle Isomorphism Example'),
      ]),
      body([
        div('.app-container', [vtree,]),
        script(`window.appContext = ${serialize(context)};`),
        // script(clientBundle),
      ]),
    ])
  );
}

let main = (sources) => {
  let vtree = (
    section('.home', [
      h1('The homepage'),
      p('Welcome to our spectacular web page with nothing special here.'),
    ])
  )
  return {
    DOM: vtree,
  }
}

let renderIndex = (request, reply) => {
  let context = xs.of({})
  Cycle.run((sources) => {
    let vtree = main(sources).DOM
    let wrappedVTree = xs.combine(vtree, context)
      .map(wrapVTreeWithHtmlBoilerplate)
      .last()
    return {
      DOM: wrappedVTree,
    };
  }, {
    DOM: makeHTMLDriver((html) => {
      let wrappedHtml = `<!doctype html>${html}`
    }),
    context: () => {return context},
    PreventDefault: () => {},
  })
}
```

You can find the full source code [here](https://github.com/aknuds1/hapi-cycle/tree/dom-not-stream).

I'm running on OS X using Node v6.6.0, babel-node 6.14.0, Hapi 15.0.3, @cycle/dom 12.2.5 and @cycle/xstream-run 3.1.0. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Please post information about JS run-times for Your local development environment and for server environment separately.

Comment: @przemo_li It's all local for now, but I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error was that the rendered VTree was not a stream. I changed the code to the following and it works:

```
let vtree = sources.context.map(({}) => {
   return (
    section('.home', [
      h1('The homepage'),
      p('Welcome to our spectacular web page with nothing special here.'),
    ])
  )
})
return {
  DOM: vtree,
}
```

The `sources.context.map` call (which I borrowed from the original isomorphic example) ensures that `vtree` is a stream.